# change the left join query based on predefined filter-clause(condition)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a fine grained SQL query

```
SELECT A.Form_Id,
      B.CONTAINER_ID,
      A.FORM_DESC,
      A.FORM_TITLE,
      A.LAYOUT,
      A.TOTAL_COLUMNS,
      COUNT (*) Over () AS Total_Rows
      ,ROW_NUMBER () OVER ( ORDER BY CONTAINER_ID ASC ) ROWNM
    FROM FORM_DEFINITION A
    LEFT JOIN
      (SELECT CONTAINER_ID,FORM_ID FROM FORM_CONTAINER_DEFINITION
      ) B
    On A.Form_Id = B.Form_Id
WHERE UPPER(TRIM(A.FORM_ID)) LIKE '%' || UPPER(TRIM('FORM2')) || '%'
```

Its working fine in SQL Developer  but we are using our own framework. It's adding a dynamic filter-clause (where condition) for every query like this

```
AND UPPER(TRIM(A.FORM_ID)) LIKE '%' || UPPER(TRIM('FORM2')) || '%'
```

but as I changed it as
 `WHERE UPPER(TRIM(A.FORM_ID)) LIKE '%' || UPPER(TRIM('FORM2')) || '%'`
I should not change the filter clause. Could you please suggest how can I modify the left-join query to use the pre defined filter-clause.

Comment: you can just keep where 1=1 and your framework will make it like "where 1=1 AND UPPER(TRIM(A.FORM_ID)) LIKE '%' || UPPER(TRIM('FORM2')) || '%'"...hope it work if I am understanding your issue.

Comment: There is a syntax error in your script, you should have `like` operator instead if the last `||`. Otherwise, I do not really understand your question.

Comment: Moreover, pls decide if your question is related to mysql or ms sql. Those are 2 different products.

Comment: hi malik , THANKS A LOT , it working fine

Comment: Tagged with `oracle` as SQL server does not support the standard `||` string concatenation and MySQL doesn't support window functions.